# Gas Pilot on Yom Tov

Tags: melacha-creative-work, yom-tov, cooking-bishul, fire-burning

A gas pilot stove is a stove which has a continuous flame running rather than using an electric sparker (although I believe such stoves are no longer legal). With this in mind, would it be necessary to light such a stove with a match, or would the pilot lamp suffice?

Answer (score 5):

Google is your friend! [The COR](http://www.cor.ca/view/169:2/cooking_on_yom_tov.html), [Chabad](http://chabad.org/708510), [the OU](https://www.ou.org/holidays/rosh-hashanah/36050/), and [the Star-K](http://www.star-k.org/articles/articles/kosher-appliances/480/oven-kashrus-for-yom-tov-use/) say you can light a burner from a pilot light on *yom tov*.

Comment: Not sure what the fuss is about. On yom tov one must not create fire but one  can increase (and perhaps decrease)it.

Comment: Many NYC apartments had used pilot light gas stoves for years. My rav had told the cong. that there was no problem lighting the stove as clearly there was an existing flame. The "problem" was that you could not turn of the stove burner once lit. Some people assumed that since the pilot stays lit, that's good enough. Halacha doesn't work that way.

Comment: Could you remove this answer from the category of link-0nly?

Comment: @Noach, I think I did so by adding the words "say you can light a burner from a pilot light on _yom tov_". I'm not sure what else I can add to this answer.